# After update Facebook IOS SDK generated dialogs we are consistently getting CAPTCHA's

Tags: ios, facebook

After Facebook IOS SDK update, our app generates a message "A Link in Your Post Might Be Unsafe" and then "Security Check Failed" when our user try to post to Facebook from the app. We never had this before Facebook SDK update. Are there any peculiarities in Facebook SDK update that we should take into account to avoid this situation in future?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Best regards,
Awem Games

Comment: What is the link you are trying to share?

Comment: Hi, LinkUrl - https://itunes.apple.com/ru/app/cradle-of-empires/id738480930?mt=8 ImageUrl - http://www.awem.com/facebook-apps/cradle-of-empires/images/*image_name*.png

Answer (score 0):

Can you post an example of the *full* url that is blocked? That way we can check what is happening.

There can be various reasons why the content you want to share is blocked. This is very unlikely linked to using a new SDK. It can be due to having testing; is that URL shared a very high amount of times since testing the new SDK?

You can use the following form to appeal for any blocked content: https://www.facebook.com/help/contact/244560538958131